# How to use `cv2.imshow` correctly for the float image returned by `cv2.distanceTransform`?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Something weird is going on with cv2.imshow. I was writing a piece of code and wondering why one of my operations wasn't working (as diagnosed by observing cv2.imshow). In exasperation I ended up writing the very same image to a file wherein it looks fine. Why is cv2.imshow showing a binary image (first image below) while cv2.imwrite writing the grayscale image as intended (second image)? I've never had problems with displaying grayscale images before!

```
cv2.imshow('Latest', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

distTransform = cv2.distanceTransform(src=image,distanceType=cv2.DIST_L2,maskSize=5)
cv2.imwrite('distanceTransform.png', distTransform)

cv2.imshow('Latest', distTransform)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the image as it's displayed by cv2.imshow:
[image: distanceTransform.png as displayed by cv2.imshow (also the same as the input image)]

This is the image as it's saved by imwrite:
[image: distanceTransform.png as written by imwrite]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When use `cv2.imshow`, you should know:

```
imshow(winname, mat) -> None
. The function may scale the image, depending on its depth:
. - If the image is 8-bit unsigned, it is displayed as is.
. - If the image is 16-bit unsigned or 32-bit integer, the pixels are divided by 256. 
    That is, the value range [0,255\*256] is mapped to [0,255].
. - If the image is 32-bit or 64-bit floating-point, the pixel values are multiplied by 255. That is, the
.   value range [0,1] is mapped to [0,255].
```

---

The function **`distaceTransform`** return type `float`. So when directly display the dist, it first multiply 255, then map to [0,255]. So the result just like binary image. `(0*255=>0, 1*255=>255, ...*255=>255)`.

**To display correctly**:

(1) you can clip the float dist to [0,255]  and change the datatype to `np.uint8` by `cv2.convertScaleAbs`

```
dist1 = cv2.convertScaleAbs(dist)
```

(2) you can also normalize float dist to [0,255] and change datatype by `cv2.normalize`

```
dist2 = cv2.normalize(dist, None, 255,0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8UC1)
```

---

Here is an example with panda:

[image]

The result:

[image]

---

Full code:

```
#!/ust/bin/python3
# 2018.01.19 10:24:58 CST
img = cv2.imread("panda.png", 0)
dist = cv2.distanceTransform(src=img,distanceType=cv2.DIST_L2,maskSize=5)
dist1 = cv2.convertScaleAbs(dist)
dist2 = cv2.normalize(dist, None, 255,0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8UC1)

cv2.imshow("dist", dist)
cv2.imshow("dist1", dist1)
cv2.imshow("dist2", dist2)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: What is CV_8UC1 and how is it different from CV_8UC2, CV_8UC3 etc.

Comment: CV_{type}C{channels}