# OpenCV watershed + otsu with distanceTransform

Tags: python, opencv, watershed

I am trying to use OpenCV watershed algorithm (https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html) but with one little change. There is this line of code in the docs:

```
ret, sure_fg = cv2.threshold(dist_transform,0.7*dist_transform.max(),255,0)
```

I need to replace this thresholding with Otsu's thresholding method if it's possible. Most of the code I use I got from the OpenCV watershed docs:

```
img = np.load('file.npy')
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations = 2)
sure_background = cv2.dilate(opening, kernel, iterations = 50)
dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(opening, cv2.DIST_L2, 5)
ret, sure_foreground = cv2.threshold(dist_transform, 0, dist_transform.max(), cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

The last line causes the error:

> /tmp/build/80754af9/opencv_1512687413662/work/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp:1402: error: (-215) src.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) in function threshold

I know that in the watershed documentation there is no Otsu's thresholding in this step, but I have to set up a script to be executed on very many images and it is important to me that it does not require the threshold value to be set up for explicitly every image.

Is there a way to run this method (cv2.threshold) on this object (the result of cv2.distanceTransform) with Otsu's thresholding?

---

**EDIT**

To be honest I did not look for similar solution in other libraries, but now I found watershed algorithm in scikit-image library (http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_watershed.html). It seems to be a little bit less complicated in use, probably will fit my needs. But the I asked may be useful to me (or someone else) later, so if anyone has the solution then please share it :)

---

**EDIT 2**

When I normalized the values by adding this line:

```
dist_transform = cv2.normalize(dist_transform, None, 255,0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8UC1)
```

it worked, but unfortunately, there is another problem. When I run the cv2.watershed method like this:

```
ret, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(sure_foreground)
labels = labels + 1
labels[unknown == 255] = 0
labels = cv2.watershed(img, labels) # this line is wrong
```

I get this as the error message:

> error: (-215) src.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((3)-1) << 3))
>   && dst.type() == (((4) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) in function
>   watershed

The reason is that the image I use is 1-channel array and watershed method requires 3-channel array (I added the loading the image above). Is there a way to fix that? Data types are correct (image is uint8, labels - int32).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is specified in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.8/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold):

> Currently, the Otsu’s method is implemented only for 8-bit images.

And the one from distance transform:

> **dst** – Output image with calculated distances. It is a 32-bit floating-point, single-channel image of the same size as src .

This means that the output of distance transform is incompatible with the one from threshold with Otsu's method...

**Possible Solution**

You can truncate the float values and convert the matrix to uint8 to be able to use it.

```
np.uint8(dist_transform)
```

This may loose some of the data, and you have to be careful with the negative values and the ones that pass 255... numpy will just give you a value like this:

```
a = np.array([3.4, 2.7, 8.9, -1.2, 267])
np.uint8(a)
# result => array([  3,   2,   8, 255,  11], dtype=uint8)
```

as you see you get -1.2 => 255 and 267 => 11 and the other numbers truncated... you may want to consider rounding the numbers or maybe normalize the values.... Everything depends on what is your objective and how is your distance transform looking like.

I hope this helps you, and remember to pay attention to the src and dst types, it is usually the most common error with OpenCV.

Comment: Thanks, it is working, but I have another error, please see the update of the first post.

Answer (score 1):

As @api55 said, OTSU is only for `CV_8UC1`. You can normalize the dist image to [0,255] by this:

```
dist2 = cv2.normalize(dist, None, 255,0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8UC1)
ret, sure_foreground = cv2.threshold(dist2, 0, int(dist.max()), cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

---

Notice:

You should not simple use `np.uint8(x)` if `x` contains element great than `255` or less than zero(to avoid underflow/overflow).

```
>>> np.uint8(300)
44
>>> np.uint8(-10)
246
```

A link may be useful for display distance map:

[How to use `cv2.imshow` correctly for the float image returned by `cv2.distanceTransform`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48331211/how-to-use-cv2-imshow-correctly-for-the-float-image-returned-by-cv2-distancet/48333272#48333272)

---

Update:

This the the distmap comparison（the third is by your method):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it is working, but I have another error, please see the update of the first post.