# cv.imshow throws (-215:Assertion failed) src_depth != CV_16F && src_depth != CV_32S in function 'convertToShow'

Tags: python, opencv

In this code i am trying to integral image  and every time i run this code
a window flash and desapear , then i get this error in terminal

```
import cv2  
import numpy as np  

image = cv2.imread("nancy.jpg")  
(rows,cols,dims) = image.shape  

sum = np.zeros((rows,cols), np.uint8)  
imageIntegral = cv2.integral(image, sum, -1) 

cv2.imshow("imageIntegral", imageIntegral) 
cv2.waitKey()
```

**Error:**

> cv2.imshow("imageIntegral",imageIntegral)cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:/projects/opencv-python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/precomp.hpp:131:
>
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) src_depth != CV_16F && src_depth !=
> CV_32S in function 'convertToShow'

Comment: It's difficult to store the sum of all previous pixels in 8 bits! The absolute minimum is 16 bits, but use 32 bits!

Comment: you mean i should change the 'np.uint8' to 'np.uint32'?

Comment: i changer the uint8 to uint32 but i get another error 
"  imageIntegral = cv2.integral(image, sum,-1)
TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'sum' "

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Help on cv2.integral:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> print(cv2.__version__)
4.0.1-dev
>>> help(cv2.integral)
Help on built-in function integral:

integral(...)
    integral(src[, sum[, sdepth]]) -> sum
    .   @overload
```

---

A simple demo:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = np.uint8(np.random.random((2,2,3))*255)
dst = cv2.integral(img)

>>> print(img.shape, img.dtype)
(2, 2, 3) uint8
>>> print(dst.shape, dst.dtype)
(3, 3, 3) int32
```

---

And you shouldn't use imshow directly on the dst image because it's not np.uint8. Normalize it to `np.uint8` (range 0 to 255) or `np.float32` (range 0.0 to 1.0). You can find the reason at this link: [How to use `cv2.imshow` correctly for the float image returned by `cv2.distanceTransform`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48331211/how-to-use-cv2-imshow-correctly-for-the-float-image-returned-by-cv2-distancet/48333272#48333272)

Answer (score 37):

Check whether your image is **uint8** or not

```
image = image.astype(np.uint8)
```

Comment: that doesn't *check*, that *converts*. -- it's also **wrong**. you should have tried that code. for an **integral image**, as in the question, it'll merely result in a more or less **noisy image**. you should have normalized before converting.

Answer (score 2):

[`cv.imshow`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563) requires the given image to have dtype from the set of `np.uint8`, `np.uint16`, `np.float32`, `np.float64`. It does not accept other types.

Your integral image has type `np.int32`. The error message explicitly rejected your data **because it was `np.int32`** (or half-float, *CV_16F*, but that's not the case here).

So, you need to convert it to a `dtype` that is acceptable to `imshow`. **Before** converting with `.astype(...)`, you must make sure that your value range is mapped into the range of 8-bit integers (0 to 255), or floats (imshow expects 0.0 to 1.0). Normalize your data using the maximum, like this:

```py
imageIntegral = cv.integral(src=image)

# division results in values ranging from 0.0 to 1.0
# type is floating point array (float64)
presentable = imageIntegral / imageIntegral.max()

cv.imshow("imageIntegral", presentable)
cv.waitKey()
cv.destroyWindow("imageIntegral")
```

input, [from OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/df2/tutorial_py_basic_ops.html):

[image: example input image]

`presentable`:

[image: presentable]

You obviously don't see much in an integral image because by its nature it's *mostly* a gradient. That is what happens when one integrates a series of values chosen from a range. That is also why `imageIntegral.astype(np.uint8)` results in **noise**:

[image: casting an integral image to uint8]