# Unable to change the value of image using numpy

Tags: python, opencv

Ive been trying to change the value of a specific value in an image using numpy. When trying to the jupyter kernel crashes and I get the message as shown. Im trying to change the blue color to become white.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

mask = cv.imread("colors.jpg")
a = mask[400,500]
print(mask[400,500])
# [204  71  63]
b = np.where(mask == a, 255, 0)
cv.imshow("mask", b)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

`error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:/Users/runneradmin/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-req-build-sn_xpupm/opencv/modules/highgui/src/precomp.hpp:155: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src_depth != CV_16F && src_depth != CV_32S in function 'convertToShow'`

Comment: Does this anwer solve your problem https://www.codestudyblog.com/sfb2002b1/0225182148.html

Comment: Brilliant! That has solved it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [integral image error code cv2.imshow("imageIntegral",imageIntegral)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55759535/integral-image-error-code-cv2-imshowimageintegral-imageintegral)