# Not able to convert RGB image to gray scale using scikit image

Tags: python, image, opencv, binary, scikit-image

I have tried to convert an RGB image to Otsu binary image (gray scale) but that doesn't seem to work as I get the error as mentioned below.

```
from cv2 import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
from skimage.util import invert
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = rgb2gray(imread('Ared.png'))
binary = img > threshold_otsu(img)
np.unique(binary)
skeleton = skeletonize(invert(binary))
cv2.imshow('original', img)
cv2.imshow('skeleton', skeleton)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result in terminal

```
  img = rgb2gray(imread('Ared.png'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "preprocessing.py", line 16, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('skeleton', skeleton)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'
```

Comment: Not an answer at all, but have you tried looking inside the `skeleton` variable (printing it for instance) ? You should check the range of its values ([0, 1] ? [0, 255] ?) and their type (float ? uint8 ?) I have the feeling the problem is not from your use of skimage, but of cv2 which is kind of picky when it is asked to display images.

Comment: Compare the datatypes (int array, float32 array etc) of img and skeleton using a debugger, they are probably different but should be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Bad exception messages are bad...

`cv2.imshow` does not handle binary arrays. The acceptable types according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48333272/3220135) answer are `uint8`, `uint16`, `int`, `float`, and `double`.

you should be able to convert the array to `uint8` with:

```
skeleton.astype('u1')
```

This will leave you with values between 0 and 1 though, which is all very dark. If you the multiply the array by 255, the colors should be black and white as expected:

```
skeleton.astype('u1') * 255
```

full example with data image from skimage:

```
from cv2 import cv2
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
from skimage.util import invert
from skimage.data import camera

img = camera()
binary = img > threshold_otsu(img)
skeleton = skeletonize(invert(binary))
cv2.imshow('original', img)
cv2.imshow('skeleton', skeleton.astype('u1')*255)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your format is wrong. You need to change it to float32. That's a common error with opencv. You can change this line to convert it to float32 and it should work fine.

```
cv2.imshow('skeleton', np.float32(skeleton))
```