# Debayering 16 bit bayer encoded Raw Images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have images that are bayer encoded (RGGB) and each pixel is 16 bit. When I unpack the byte file and read the image, it appears greenish. I wonder what next image processing steps I should apply. 1200 X 1648, 16 bits per pixel.

I have tried using simple-image-debayer and colour-demosaicing libraries but I get a white image as a result.

The main area of the code (my point of doubt) is inside the if(bands == 1). I am unable to produce the right coloured image. I see a greenish image which i believe is because of the RGGB CFA.

LINK TO IMAGE IS :
https://pds-imaging.jpl.nasa.gov/data/mars2020/mars2020_mastcamz_sci_calibrated/data/0206/rad/ZL0_0206_0685235537_613RAD_N0071836ZCAM08234_1100LMA02.IMG

```
image_path = "ZL0_0206_0685235537_613RAD_N0071836ZCAM08234_1100LMA02.IMG"

import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import struct
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
import os
import shutil
import time

import colour
from colour_demosaicing import demosaicing_CFA_Bayer_Malvar2004,demosaicing_CFA_Bayer_Menon2007     

#############  convert image to png  #############

def readHeader(file):
    # print("Calling readHeader")
    f = open(file,'rb')
    continuing = 1
    count = 0
    
    h_bytes = -1
    h_lines = -1
    h_line_samples = -1
    h_sample_type = 'UNSET' #MSB_INTEGER, IEEE_REAL
    h_sample_bits = -1
    h_bands = -1
    while continuing == 1:
        line = f.readline()
        count = count + 1
        arr = str(line, 'utf8').split("=")
        arr[0] = str(arr[0]).strip()
        if 'BYTES' == arr[0] and len(arr[0])>1:
            h_bytes=int(str(arr[1]).strip())
        elif 'LINES' == arr[0] and len(arr[0])>1: 
            h_lines=int(str(arr[1]).strip())
        elif 'LINE_SAMPLES' == arr[0] and len(arr[0])>1:
            h_line_samples=int(str(arr[1]).strip())
        elif 'SAMPLE_TYPE' == arr[0] and len(arr[0])>1:
            h_sample_type=str(arr[1]).strip()
        elif 'SAMPLE_BITS' == arr[0] and len(arr[0])>1:
            h_sample_bits = int(str(arr[1]).strip())
        elif 'BANDS' == arr[0] and len(arr[0])>1: 
            h_bands=int(str(arr[1]).strip())
        if (line.endswith(b'END\r\n') or count>600):
            continuing = 0
    f.close()
    return h_bytes, h_lines,h_line_samples,h_sample_type,h_sample_bits,h_bands

def readImage(file, pixelbytes, sample_type,sample_bits, lines, line_samples, bands):
    # print("Calling Read image")
    f = open(file,'rb')
    filesize = os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size
    h_bytes = filesize - pixelbytes
    f.seek(h_bytes) # skip past the header bytes
    
    fmt = '{endian}{pixels}{fmt}'.format(endian='>', pixels=lines*line_samples*bands, fmt=getFmt(sample_type,sample_bits))
    
    if (bands==3):
        print(pixelbytes,lines,line_samples,fmt)
        img = np.array(struct.unpack(fmt,f.read(pixelbytes))).reshape(bands,lines,line_samples)    
        print(img)
        m = np.max(np.max(img, axis=1))
        img = np.clip(img/m,0,1) #normalize and clip so values are between 0 and 1
        img = np.stack([img[0,:,:],img[1,:,:],img[2,:,:]],axis=2)
        # print(img.shape)

    elif (bands==1):
        print(pixelbytes,lines,line_samples,fmt)
        img = np.array(struct.unpack(fmt,f.read(pixelbytes))).reshape(lines,line_samples)    
        # data = np.fromfile(f, np.uint8, line_samples * lines * 3//2)
        # data = data.astype(np.uint16)  # Cast the data to uint16 type.
        # result = np.zeros(data.size*2//3, np.uint16)
        # img = np.array(struct.unpack(fmt,f.read(pixelbytes))).reshape(lines,line_samples)    
        # result[0::2] = ((data[1::3] & 15) << 8) | data[0::3]
        # result[1::2] = (data[1::3] >> 4) | (data[2::3] << 4)
        # bayer_im = np.reshape(result, (lines, line_samples))
        img = cv2.cvtColor(np.uint16(img), cv2.COLOR_BAYER_BG2BGR)

    return img
    # return img
    
    
# fmtMap - converts sample_type from header to python format fmt. 
def getFmt(sample_type, samplebits):
    # print("Calling getFM funtion")
    if (sample_type=='IEEE_REAL'):
        return 'f'
    elif (sample_type=='MSB_INTEGER'):
        return 'H'
    elif (sample_type=='UNSIGNED_INTEGER'):
        return 'B'
    else:
        return 'X'



def convert_to_png(sol_folder_path):

  hbytes,hlines,hline_samples,hsample_type,hsample_bits,hbands = readHeader(full_path)
  numpixels = hlines * hline_samples * hbands
  pixelbytes = numpixels*hsample_bits//8 # // is for integer division
            
  img = readImage(full_path, pixelbytes, hsample_type,hsample_bits, hlines, hline_samples, hbands)
  plt.imsave('debayer_test.png',np.uint8(img))
```

Comment: old question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73663283/debayering-raw-images

Comment: @RadhikaGanapathy please delete your previous question. We don't want the new question to be considered a "duplication"...

Answer (score 0):

A raw image in [Bayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_filter) mosaic format is a "single band" image.
After applying [Demosaicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demosaicing) algorithm, the output is 3 color channels image (RGB).

After skipping the header, we may read the raw data, and apply Demosaicing in few steps:

- Read raw data bytes (1200 * 1648 * 2 bytes):

  ```
   data = f.read(pixelbytes)
  ```
- Convert data bytes to `uint16` NumPy array and reshape to image dimensions:

  ```
   img = np.frombuffer(data, np.uint16).reshape(lines, line_samples)
  ```
- Convert from [big endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) to little endian format by swapping high and low bytes of each `uint16` element (required because the input format is big endian):

  ```
   img = (img >> 8) + (img << 8)
  ```
- Apply Demosaicing using OpenCV `cvtColor` method (convert from Bayer to BGR):

  ```
   img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BAYER_BG2BGR)
  ```

---

As a "bonus" I added [Gamma correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) (using standard [sRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB) gamma transfer function).

After applying gamma correction (or without gamma correction), we may convert the result to type `uint8` and save as PNG.
For converting `uint16` to `uint8` we may scale by `255/(2**16-1)`.

---

Code sample:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2

def readHeader(file):
    # print("Calling readHeader")
    f = open(file,'rb')
    continuing = 1
    count = 0
    
    h_bytes = -1
    h_lines = -1
    h_line_samples = -1
    h_sample_type = 'UNSET' #MSB_INTEGER, IEEE_REAL
    h_sample_bits = -1
    h_bands = -1
    while continuing == 1:
        line = f.readline()
        count = count + 1
        arr = str(line, 'utf8').split("=")
        arr[0] = str(arr[0]).strip()
        if 'BYTES' == arr[0] and len(arr[0])>1:
            h_bytes=int(str(arr[1]).strip())
        elif 'LINES' == arr[0] and len(arr[0])>1: 
            h_lines=int(str(arr[1]).strip())
        elif 'LINE_SAMPLES' == arr[0] and len(arr[0])>1:
            h_line_samples=int(str(arr[1]).strip())
        elif 'SAMPLE_TYPE' == arr[0] and len(arr[0])>1:
            h_sample_type=str(arr[1]).strip()
        elif 'SAMPLE_BITS' == arr[0] and len(arr[0])>1:
            h_sample_bits = int(str(arr[1]).strip())
        elif 'BANDS' == arr[0] and len(arr[0])>1: 
            h_bands=int(str(arr[1]).strip())
        if (line.endswith(b'END\r\n') or count>600):
            continuing = 0
    f.close()
    return h_bytes, h_lines,h_line_samples,h_sample_type,h_sample_bits,h_bands


def readImage(file, pixelbytes, sample_type,sample_bits, lines, line_samples, bands):
    f = open(file,'rb')
    filesize = os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size
    h_bytes = filesize - pixelbytes
    f.seek(h_bytes) # skip past the header bytes
       
    # Assume bands = 1
    print(pixelbytes, lines, line_samples)

    data = f.read(pixelbytes)  # Read raw data bytes
    img = np.frombuffer(data, np.uint16).reshape(lines, line_samples)  # Convert to uint16 NumPy array and reshape to image dimensions.
    img = (img >> 8) + (img << 8)  # Convert from big endian to little endian
      
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BAYER_BG2BGR)  # Apply demosaicing (convert from Bayer to BGR).

    return img
    

def lin2rgb(im):
    """ Convert im from "Linear sRGB" to sRGB - apply Gamma. """
    # sRGB standard applies gamma = 2.4, Break Point = 0.00304 (and computed Slope = 12.92)    
    # lin2rgb MATLAB functions uses the exact formula [we may approximate it to power of (1/gamma)].
    g = 2.4
    bp = 0.00304
    inv_g = 1/g
    sls = 1 / (g/(bp**(inv_g - 1)) - g*bp + bp)
    fs = g*sls / (bp**(inv_g - 1))
    co = fs*bp**(inv_g) - sls*bp

    srgb = im.copy()
    srgb[im <= bp] = sls * im[im <= bp]
    srgb[im > bp] = np.power(fs*im[im > bp], inv_g) - co
    return srgb


def convert_to_png(full_path):
    hbytes, hlines, hline_samples, hsample_type, hsample_bits, hbands = readHeader(full_path)
    numpixels = hlines * hline_samples * hbands
    pixelbytes = numpixels*hsample_bits//8 # // is for integer division
            
    img = readImage(full_path, pixelbytes, hsample_type,hsample_bits, hlines, hline_samples, hbands)

    # Apply gamma correction, and convert to uint8
    img_in_range_0to1 = img.astype(np.float32) / (2**16-1)  # Convert to type float32 in range [0, 1] (before applying gamma correction).
    gamma_img = lin2rgb(img_in_range_0to1)
    gamma_img = np.round(gamma_img * 255).astype(np.uint8)  # Convert from range [0, 1] to uint8 in range [0, 255].

    cv2.imwrite('gamma_img.png', gamma_img)  # Save image after demosaicing and gamma correction.

    # Show the uint16 image and gamma_img for testing
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    cv2.imshow('gamma_img', gamma_img)
    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


image_path = "ZL0_0206_0685235537_613RAD_N0071836ZCAM08234_1100LMA02.IMG"

convert_to_png(image_path)
```

---

Output (downscaled):
[image]

---

The colors are probably not perfect...

When applying raw image processing, there is a lot of "color science" (for getting the right colors), but the subject exceeds the scope of the question.

Comment: This is amazing! I really appreciate your explanation. 

I am facing an issue though, I was using matplotlib to save the final png for the band 3 images. However when I use cv2, the band 3 images are black for some reason.

Comment: Are you asking me to guess? I guess that the images are `uint16`, but the pixel values are much lower than 65535 (2^16-1). What is the `dtype` of the NumPy array used as input to `cv2.imshow`?

Comment: The band 3 images are a float64 :(

Comment: What is the minimum and maximum pixel value? Try the solution in the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48331211/how-to-use-cv2-imshow-correctly-for-the-float-image-returned-by-cv2-distancet).

Comment: I a few questions. How can I improve the resolution of these images? Why is there a black line on either sides of the image? Is it because of the normalization?

Comment: Improving the resolution is probably not the right term. We can improve the visibility by enhancing the contrast, and sharpen the image (and improving the colors). Sharpening increases the noise, so usually we need to apply noise reduction (there are many algorithms). The black margins exist because the true resolution of the sensor is not 1648x1200, but a bit less. It is common that raw images have black margins (maybe the size of the margins is given in the header).

Comment: Answering the previous question the minimum and maximum pixel value in the resulting array is 0 and 1 respectively.

Comment: `float64` type in range [0, 1] is not supposed to be black when using `cv2.imshow`. I don't know why is it black.